# How to load custom properties file depending upon active profile in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, profile

In my spring boot application I have made info-local.properties and info-dev.properties
How do I access the correct one based on current active profile?

Answer (score 1):

**Environment-Specific Properties File**

The naming convention of spring-boot properties file is `application-<profile>.properties` to get it automatically read without any extra line of code. You should rename your properties file as `application-local.properties` and `application-dev.properties`.

Click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring#2-environment-specific-properties-file) for reference.

**Set Profiles**

There are various ways to activate any specific profile. The easiest ways are:

1. [JVM System Parameter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#4-jvm-system-parameter) : Add `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` to VM args while running.
2. [Application Properties](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#1-activating-or-setting-a-profile) : Add `spring.profiles.active=dev` in the common `application.properties` file .

Click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#set-profiles) for another way around.

**Load properties manually**

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:info-${envTarget}.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

`${envTarget}` will get resolved by the active profile, and it will load the correct `info-xxx` properties into `PropertiesWithJavaConfig`.
Click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring#java) for reference.

Comment: Thanks. How do u do that for custom yaml file that is not application yml.   Look like spring only auto append the profile to properties and yaml whose names are application. Wonder why it can't do that for custom name properties/yaml

Comment: Cos @propertysource don't support yaml, if I not wrong

Answer (score -1):

Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application configuration and make it only available in certain environments.

- A simple solution for you would be to just start the application like
  this:

  --spring.profiles.active=local,dev
- You can also annotate your main config class specifying what profile
  you want:

  @Configuration
  @Profile("production")
  class MainConfig{..
  }
- You can programmatically set active profiles by calling
  **SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles(...)** before your application runs. It is also possible to activate profiles using
  Spring’s ConfigurableEnvironment interface.

I will also leave a link with an example for this:
[Spring profiles example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: The main issue is to load an `info-XXX.properties` file, which this answer doesn't help with. Not useful.